# .load() with success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked many times before...

I have a simple `('#Div').load(file.php?id='+id+'&page='+page)`

The on click event acts as follows

```
function recp(id) {  
  var user = $('#page').attr('page'); 
  $("#button").hide()
  $("#loading").html('<img src="images/loader.gif">');
  $('#div').load('file.php?id='+id+'&page='+page); 
  $("#loading").empty();
  $("#button1").show()
}
```

I have a similar process on my site with ajax post, works very nicely, but I can't seem to get this to work with `.load()`.

Would need a bit of advice. Cheers.

Comment: Could you show your actual code, please?

Comment: modified the question (with added code)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is that `load` is asynchronous.  The function call returns *before* the AJAX request is complete.  If you have code that needs to be executed after the request is complete, you need to use the `complete` callback specified in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#div').load('file.php?id='+id+'&page='+page, function(){
    $("#loading").empty();
    $("#button1").show();
});
```

Comment: This really helped Thanks mate