# JQuery Waiting for .load's

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have a few jQuery.load Requests.
But I only want to show the results if all loads are successfull and are ready.

I found "queue" but I'm not sure weather this is the right.
http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Does anyone know more than I ?

I tried this now, it doesn't works.

```
function ShowInfos(Code)
{   
    $.when( asyncLoadInfos(Code) ).then(
        function( status ) {
            alert( status + ", things are going well" );
        },
        function( status ) {
            alert( status + ", you fail this time" );
        },
        function( status ) {
            //Infos einblenden
            ShowGrid();
            alert(status + "Yeah");
        }
        );
}


function asyncLoadInfos(Code)
{
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    //Generelle Infos laden
    $('someDiv').load(customerURI, function()
    {
      //Here is some Action, not relevant fot the topic
    });


    $("anootherDiv").load(todoURI, function()
    {
        //Unrelevant Code, too
    });


    $("abc").load(phoneNoteURI, function()
    {

        });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: queue is not the right way to do it. It could work, but it's the wrong tool for the job. What you want are deferred/promise objects.

Comment: I tried it with your idea, but it doesn't work, i get no alert.

Comment: you never resolved the deferred object. each instance of .load would need it's own deferred object that gets resolved on success.

Comment: @Kevin B Thank you, I got it ! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery : wait until all ajax calls finish then continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952387/jquery-wait-until-all-ajax-calls-finish-then-continue)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery.load has a complete function. This way you can check success of your ajax-loading.
Read more: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734648/load-with-success-function)
Also, look at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
And the example:

```
$('#content').load(get_info.php,function(){
alert('Content has been loaded');
});
```

Comment: This is clear, but I have more than one jQuery.load() and I want to do something when ALL loads are done.

Comment: If you posted relevant code in your question we would know that you already knew this.

Comment: You can see this information in the first setence "I have a few jQuery.load Requests" I added my Code in the first post now, thank you.